# Base URL of Mojolicious response

Tags: html, perl, http, mojolicious

The [`HTTP::Response`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) module has a `base` method that returns the base URL to use when converting relative URLs in the content of the message to absolute ones. It retrieves it from the message body (as a `<base>` element inside the HTML `<head>`), the HTTP header `Content-Location` (or the obsolete `Content-Base`), or the requested URL (from the most recent redirect, if any)

I can't see any way that [`Mojo::Message::Response`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Message::Response) provides the same information, and I don't want to have to code it myself if it's already in there somewhere

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

**Update**   At this point I think that this framework doesn't have an equivalent of `base` from `LWP`

---

I am finding the [content_location](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Headers#content_location) method in [Mojo::Headers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Headers) class. The [Mojo::Message::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Message::Response) inherits from the base [Mojo::Message](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Message) and `Mojo::Headers` seems to be picked up as well

Adding to the example from synopsis

```
my $res = Mojo::Message::Response->new;
$res->parse("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\x0d\x0a");
$res->parse("Content-Length: 12\x0d\x0a");
$res->parse("Content-Type: text/plain\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a");
$res->parse('Hello World!');
say $res->code;
say $res->headers->content_type;
say $res->body;

say $res->headers->content_location // 'location not defined';  # /
$res->headers->content_location('set_some_location');
say $res->headers->content_location // 'location not defined';
```

seems to work.  Is this suitable?  I can't readily find a real page to try with.

This doesn't scan the document content but only works with headers. The `LWP` sets headers from the document when producing the [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object, as explained in the question and under `base`. In my tests (v5.16) `Mojo::UA` doesn't do that. I couldn't find a direct capability for this.

One way to obtain base URL would then be via DOM, for instance

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $base_url = $ua->get($url)
    ->res->dom
    ->at('head')->at('base')->attr('href');
```

The method `dom` is from `Mojo::Message` while `base` and `attr` are in [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM).  Or

```
$dom->at('head > base[href]');
```

which returns a hashref `{ href => URL }`, while the first example returns the URL.

The `at` returns `undef` on failure so one first needs to check.

This is an additional, manual search through the content but at least it's focused in `<head>`.

---

**Update**

I have looked over the source code of the mentioned components and their parent classes. This also brought up [Mojo::Content](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-7.29/lib/Mojo/Content.pm) whose subclass `Single` is returned by `Mojo::Message::content`, and [Mojo::UserAgent::Transactor](http://search.cpan.org/~jhthorsen/Mojolicious-5.17/lib/Mojo/UserAgent/Transactor.pm) with its `redirect` method, that makes use of [Mojo::URL](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-7.29/lib/Mojo/URL.pm).  However, they have different purposes. Altogether I found no help to directly unearth the base URL.

At this point I have to conclude that a direct capability like `base` in `LWP` isn't available here.

Comment: Should the  Mojo ua not produce these objects?

Comment: @simbabque  Right, I would hope so, but I don't know for fact that it does.

Comment: @simbabque: *"Should the Mojo ua not produce these objects?"* That's pretty much where I'm coming from. I would think so, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @zdim: Yeah, `$res->headers->content_location` just returns the value of the HTTP header, while `$dom->at('head base')->attr('href')` just returns any URL in the a `<base>` element. The base URL is one of these *or* the request URL of the most recent redirection, depending which of them exists. I can find all of them separately and use the first to be found, but I would have hoped that something like this which is part of the HTTP specification would be coded into the module.

Comment: @zdim: *"This implies searching through the content"* That doesn't matter. The DOM has to be built and searched anyway, because it is the source of the relative URLs that I need a base URL for.

Comment: @Borodin  Right, I understand the quest. I expected it to be found, too, and spent hours bouncing around documentation and all those various components.  I will look more, but at this point it seems to me that it just isn't there.  I added the DOM part merely to complete the statement.

Comment: @Borodin As for DOM and searching throught it, I meant that it would be nice that one doesn't have to reprocess by hand.  I am a little surprised that UA doesn't check for `<base>`.  (Also: it apparently _does not_ redirect by default.)

Comment: The OP asked especially about the `base` method in a spirit of the `HTTP::Response`. (which has implemented it - with a nice amount of logic behind). AFAIK in the Mojolicious for the `M::M::Response` you need write it yourself (or clone it from the `M::M::Request`, which in turn has the `Mojo::URL` which has the `base` method... :D :D )

Comment: @Nemo  Well, yes, and I haven't found it.  I couldn't see how to use `Mojo::URL::base` to do anything like what is needed here.  It's a separate class that has to be instantiated with its own URL which it then converts between rel and abs, for all I could see. I don't think that it can run with an existing `Mojo::UA` object (or, rather, transaction or response objects). I don't think it's meant to.  Please post an answer if you know how to do that!

Comment: @Borodin  At this point I have to call it and conclude for myself that it just isn't there.  Of course, I cannot make definitive statements on such a sprawling framework, but I did look through sources and everything that came up.  (The docs did leave me wanting them to be far better.)  I updated with a mention of a couple more classes that came up.